# Problem loading multiple units into multiple medivacs

Tags: starcraft-2

When selecting a group of units (marines/marauders/medivacs) I'm looking for a quick way to load them. Right-clicking each medivac in turn works, but when multiple medivacs are used they tend to converge on the right clicked one. This makes if difficult to right click the subsequent ones if they all try to stack. It takes time waiting for them to move away from the previous loaded one before I can start to load the others.
This is the quickest way to load but still painfully slow. Ideally what I'm looking for is to select lots of varying units and using a keyboard shortcut to load the land units into the also selected medivacs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you know that you can press `shift` to queue commands?

You can select all your units and right click the medivacs holding `shift`, this will make them load into the first and move on to the second one when that one is full without you having to issue more commands manually.

Comment: Seriously @Juan: I did not...

Comment: I did know about shift clicking but never thought to try it with medivacs. It still requires some ninja clicking to get every one queued before they stack on top of each other. But still it's better than the alternative. Thanks for the response

Comment: I don't think there's a better way @Dan, if I find one I'll update my answer. Good luck!